# How to convert string permission to mode_t type

Tags: c, file, permissions, chmod, stat

I am writing a program which changes file permissions. The permissions will be passed through a command line argument as a `char *` and then converted to `mode_t` type and given to [chmod()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chmod.2.html).

How could I change a string permission/mode to `mode_t`?

For example given a string `4777` aka `rwsrwxrwx` how could `4777` be changed to `mode_t`?

Comment: Security concern: the mode `4777` is a stupid set of permissions to set on any file.  It allows anyone to write any code they choose and run it as the owner of the program — which is a recipe for disaster.  I'd argue SUID (and SGID) programs should never be writable by anyone; certainly not by anyone other than the owner.  But that's tangential to your question.  (Some systems may apply extra constraints, but under classic POSIX-based systems, `4777` mode is extremely dangerous.)

Comment: Converting symbolic 'change mode' options as supported by the [`chmod`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/chmod.html) command is considerably more difficult than processing pure numeric modes.

Comment: thanks for the concern, i agree this is a dangerous set of permissions but i just used it for the sake of an example. In real life i would be sure to be more careful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse a string to extract an octal value by calling [strtol](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) and providing `8` as the base:

```
int mode = strtol(str, NULL, 8);
```

To be safe, you might want to do some additional sanity checks:

```
// Extract file mode from a string, with sanity checks.
// Returns non-zero on success. 
int string_to_filemode(const char* str, mode_t* mode)
{
    char* end = NULL;
    *mode = (mode_t)strtol(str, &end, 8);
    if (!end) return 0;
    while(isspace(*end)) end++;
    return *end == '\0' && (unsigned)*mode < 010000;
}
```

Here is an example using this:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <sys/stat.h>

int string_to_filemode(const char* str, mode_t* mode)
{
    char* end = NULL;
    *mode = (mode_t)strtol(str, &end, 8);
    if (!end) return 0;
    while(isspace(*end)) end++;
    return *end == '\0' && (unsigned)*mode < 010000;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        mode_t mode;
        if (string_to_filemode(argv[i], &mode))
            printf("Mode: str=%s val=%04o\n", argv[i], mode);
        else
            printf("Invalid mode: %s\n", argv[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output, when invoked with command-line arguments `4777 644 1000 11232 91 abc -1`:

```
Mode: str=4777 val=4777
Mode: str=644 val=0644
Mode: str=1000 val=1000
Invalid mode: 11232
Invalid mode: 91
Invalid mode: abc
Invalid mode: -1
```

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/4nhW9G9jM

Comment: what does ```if (!end)``` do? i think it checks if the first non integer character in the string is either ```NULL``` or ```\0``` aka a value that is not ```true```, i think?

Comment: `!end` is equivalent to `end == NULL`. It has nothing to do with the characters in the string. It's a pointer test.